# undefined reference in g++ (on code which compiled before)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to compile an example from a library called largenet2, using g++. I have compiled this code before on this system, but for some reason it won't do it now:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -llargenet2-0.3 -O2 vm.cpp -o shazam
```

It produces "undefined reference" errors like:

```
vm.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc2): undefined reference to `largenet::Graph::nodes()'
```

(I know this must be some silly flag or something, but googling so far produced nothing to help me....)

Thanks :)

Comment: Try moving the library being linked `largenet2-.0.3` to the end. The link order matters for `ld`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea,but it unfortunately did not change much.

Comment: Where's the implementation of `largenet::Graph::nodes()` suppose to be? Does 'largenet2' not provide that?

Comment: "it did not change much" - what did it actually change?

Comment: Scratch that - this worked ;) I was checking with the wrong file.

Comment: It seems one of the example files in this library had some outdated code..... thanks greatwolf- your tip helped me out!